# xcopy and timeouts

Tags: windows, xcopy

Related to this question and this answer [Backup on disc using TrueCrypt corruption problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/48839/backup-on-disc-using-truecrypt-corruption-problem/50829#50829)

I want to copy the backup to my HD. However the timeout seems to be a problem. I see many single files then i see

```
File creation error - Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
```

and its currently trying to copy the next file. When i click my computer i see nothing and it also locks up for some seconds (30 maybe)

So TrueCrypt is not a good solution if i must be able to copy files back from a volume with a corrupted sector? (answer in other thread please).

Is there any way for me to change the timeout? I look here for some flags and didnt see any http://www.scriptlogic.com/support/CustomScripts/XCOPYCommandLineParameters.html

Comment: Not writing as a answer because it won't help with your problem, however may I recommend that you try robocopy. It supports stop / restart and tons of other features so when you do get these timeouts, you can just resume! - Microsoft even offer a GUI for it - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx (they link to a even newer version that may be better, but I prefer the original!)

Comment: seconding robocopy- much better idea for network backups on win32.

Answer (score 1):

One school of thought would say that if the file is corrupt anyway, all that a backup of it would give you is the ability to restore some corruption, so using the /C switch on xcopy is a viable approach.

You should be aware however that xcopy can occasionally misreport a corruption on what is a perfectly good file.  One place I've definitely seen this before is where the full path to the file exceeds the Windows limit, so maybe you need to double-check if that is actually the case before resorting to alternatives (especially if you're otherwise satisfied with what you've got).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a timeout issue. My guess is that true crypt doesn't handle the corrupted section gracefully enough. And so create problems for the explorer.

Try to exclude the problematic files from the copy process ( and use robocopy as others suggests ).